# Does collecting Dr. Fetus increase odds of finding other bomb-related pick-ups?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

In two recent playthroughs, I've picked up Dr. Fetus early on, followed shortly by other bomb-type pickups - Bobby Bomb, Mr. Mega. I seldom see these pickups, so I'm wondering if gaining Dr. Fetus increases the chances of also gaining the related items?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything that says that this is the case, but give me a week and I can ask a relative who has beaten the game a ton of times and frequently gets Dr. Fetus.

Comment: I've only gotten Dr. Fetus once but the exact same thing happened to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not.  It merely has synergy with other bomb items.  Your circumstances were a by-product of the Roguelike (Random Generation) factor, and not the Dr. Fetus jar.

[Here](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Dr._Fetus) is the Wiki page with all the items that stack with it.